# Storing data files in separate physical drives

Tags: performance, sql-server-2016

Does storing sql server data files for 1 database in different drives gain performance? Is it recommended to do so? Any benefits gained from splitting the data files to multiple physical drives? There is no partition tables .The db is oltp which is read and write intensive.

Example database 
AdventureWorks

```
D:\Data\AdventureWorks_1.mdf
D:\Data\AdventureWorks_1.ndf
E:\Data\AdventureWorks_2.ndf
F:\Data\AdventureWorks_3.ndf
F:\Data\AdventureWorks_4.ndf
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, **generally** the best option is the [S.A.M.E.](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-and-raid) for all databases!

Stripe And Mirror Everything - also known as [RAID 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_RAID_levels#RAID_10) (or RAID 1+0).

> According to manufacturer specifications and official independent
>   benchmarks, in most cases RAID 10[8] provides better throughput and
>   latency than all other RAID levels[9] except RAID 0 (which wins in
>   throughput).[10] Thus, it is the preferable RAID level for
>   I/O-intensive applications such as database, email, and web servers,
>   as well as for any other use requiring high disk performance.[11]

As you can see from the oracle-base link (an absolutely **super** site for all things Oracle BTW), you can see that this is the preferred **general** RAID level for Oracle - with the proviso that one can delve a bit deeper and use other RAID levels for different file types (data, logs, control files...). See the table in the link below,

[image]

but this is the take-home message (IMHO) - in the `RAID Levels` section:

> 1+0 or 10     As the name suggests this is a combination of RAID 1 and
>   RAID 0. This sounds like it should be the same as 0+1, but it is
>   subtly different. Each disk is mirrored individually and striping
>   occurs across all the mirrored pairs. This is the best RAID for
>   Oracle.

So, 1+0 is definitely the preferred option.

Microsoft's page [RAID Levels and SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms190764(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) also says:

> RAID 10 provides the performance benefits of disk striping with the
>   disk redundancy of mirroring. RAID 10 provides the highest
>   read-and-write performance of any one of the other RAID levels, but at
>   the expense of using two times as many disks.

Note that last bit `but at the expense of using two times as many disks` - one gets nothing for nothing! "Yae cannae beet the laws o' physics, Jim..." (with apologies to Gene Roddenberry).

For completeness, [Severalnines](https://severalnines.com/database-blog/setting-optimal-environment-postgresql) (a top PostgreSQL consulting company) says:

> Setting up RAID for the database drives not only protects from data
>   loss, it can also improve performance if using the right RAID
>   configuration. RAID 1 or 10 are generally thought to be the best, and
>   10 offers parity and overall speed.

and for MySQL, consider Percona's [advice](https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/07/03/linux-os-tuning-for-mysql-database-performance/) (Percona are a very highly regarded MySQL consulting group with their own fork of the server):

> The best performance without making compromises to redundancy is
>   achieved by the use of an advanced controller with a battery-backed
>   cache unit and preferably RAID-10 volumes spanned across multiple
>   disks.

So, again **generally**, RAID 1+0 is considered the optimal solution. However, if you read around this topic, you will see that there are issues such as expense - no organisation has infinite resources, so decisions are sometimes made on budgetary grounds not to go with RAID 1+0 but rather RAID 5.

This, IMHO, is a **huge** mistake - it's a false economy. You might be saving some money on disks, but your employees' and customers' time (and sanity) are valuable resources in their own right (painful past experience, but I've had therapy and I'm OK now...).

So, ideally, it is better to spread data across disks. To answer the part of your question about if one is running more than one database on the same server, then questions of multi-tenancy arise.

For example, you have to ask yourself "If I take down the system, that's two clients gone or would I rather be able to take them down separately if required?". That's a question which only the stakeholders in your own organisation can answer - Management, Customers, DBA's...

Personlly, I would keep separate clients' data as separate as possible, but again you have budget considerations - a separate disk subsystem for each client, software licencing issues and the like. My advice is to read deeply around the area in order to be able to provide a sound strategy for your own organisation given the resources to hand.

p.s. +1 for an interesting question and welcome to the forum!

Comment: `RAID 1+0 (or 0+1)` - be careful with 0+1. A stripe-set of mirrors (1+0, RAID 0 over RAID 1 arrays) can survive four of the six two-drive faiure combinations but a mirror of stripsets (0+1, RAID 1 over RAID 0 arrays) can only survive the other two. The performance characteristics of the two are practically identical.

Comment: Regarding RAID5 or 6: yes, write performance with these can suffer. An in-between option is variants of RAID10 that work over three drives. You don't get as much space as RAID5 but don't get the read-before-write perf hit. Some hardware RAID controllers support this (often calling it "RAID 1E"), as does Linux's software RAID10 support, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_RAID_levels#RAID_1E & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_RAID_levels#Linux_MD_RAID_10.

Comment: @DavidSpillett - the oracle-base page states `1+0 or 10  As the name suggests this is a combination of RAID 1 and RAID 0. This sounds like it should be the same as 0+1, but it is subtly different. Each disk is mirrored individually and striping occurs across all the mirrored pairs. This is the best RAID for Oracle.` - so it does show that they're not identical - and definitely favours 1+0. But, as I said to the OP, it's a topic around which reading is necessary. The 1+0/0+1 distinction is subtle and the whole RAID area can be very tricky - and then if you add ZFS into the picture...

Answer (score 0):

"It depends" is the only real answer to that.

If there is lots of write activity in different tables then spreading those tables over different drives can make quite a bit of difference especially for traditional spinning disk based drives (note: contrary to popular belief SSDs *do* suffer from random access latency, more so for writes, just not remotely as much so as traditional drives). But if you are manually spreading data by table/index by creating them in different filegroups you might find the benefits do not outweigh the hassle. It will only help when there is a lot of activity on tables that are on different drives.

You might find a much better performance benefit overall, or at least a better benefit/hassle ratio, just by stripping your drives with RAID10 (or if your controller/software supports using a RAID1 array that way, that will do too). This may not have the same peak performance benefit of manually optimising data locations, but it will potentially increase throughput for *all* operations.

Also before considering breaking data files over multiple spindles, first look at keeping transaction logs on different drive(s) to the data files, and keeping tempdb separate also. Everything written to the data files goes through the tlog first so you are spreading the write load between drives that way too, and keeping tempdb separate stops spills to disk there due to heavy queries affecting the IO of other active transactions as much as they otherwise would.

If your common working set fits in the server's RAM than you'll not see much difference from any of the above for read heavy loads, because they'll be reading from RAM most of the time so their performance will be memory bandwidth and/or CPU bound.

**The best way to know for sure** is to perform proper [load tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing) to benchmark your application in different circumstances with different disk layouts. Be sure to test workloads with realistic access and concurrency patterns compared to actual application use. If you don't have the hardware to do that for real you can perhaps use virtual machines, throttling the IOPs & throughput of each vdisk artificially so that the per vdisk limits are the bottlenecks you are testing against rather than the overall random access performance of the host's drive(s).